# More details Symfony3 Profiler

Tags: symfony

I have this output from Symfony;

The controller is taking the longest, but how can I get a more detailed via of the exact functions calls that are taking the longest?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Stopwatch component](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/stopwatch.html):

```
public function bottleNeckAction()
{
    $stopwatch = $this->get('debug.stopwatch');

    $stopwatch->start('someServiceCall');
    $this->someServiceCall();
    $stopwatch->stop('someServiceCall');

    //…
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is that output using `$event->getPeriods();` ?

Comment: @JakeN yes, each periods are marked with [*line out*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qZWe.png)

Comment: Superb, I used this age ago, but did not know it linked into the Profiler. Super handy.

Comment: @JakeN btw, as I looked at your screenshot, I persume your problem is loading large, too complex data and hydrate them into objects. Take a look at [blogpost by Ocramius about that](https://ocramius.github.io/blog/doctrine-orm-optimization-hydration/).

Comment: Thanks, and the issue is sort of that. Its a huge query and then its doing lots to it. But I though that using `return $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` would get around the doctrine issue of hydration and generally just being slow?

Comment: @JakeN try `$em->createQuery('…')->getArrayResult();` to load data by Doctrine into associative array and you should spot the difference.

Comment: Hmm I think the difference here is that I am using the actual connection here rather than Doctrine - so maybe its not hydrating?